# Access Violation error while using functionality of nested DLLs

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I will start with brief of the work.

1. Function `setValue()` is part of `consoleIP.dll`.
2. Function `setValue()` is exported also.
3. Function Add() is part of calcFun.dll.
4. Function Add() is also exported.
5. Function Add() used Function `setValue()` via `LoadLibary()` and `GetProcAddress()`. `GetProcAddress` use handle of `calcFun.dll`.
6. Now `test.exe` loads and use functions of `calcFun.dll` using `LoadLibary()` and `GetProcAddress()`. `GetProcAddress()` use handle of `consoleIP.dll`

All `dlls` and `exe` are different projects.

//consoleIP.dll code

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void setValue(float * a, float * b);
void setValue(float * a, float * b){
    printf("Enter value of a and b");
    scanf("%f %f", a,b);
}
```

//calcFun.dll code

```
typedef void (__cdecl * setValDll)(float *,float *);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) float Add(void);
float firstIp;
float secondIp;

float Add(void){
    HMODULE  hmodule;
    setValDll setValDllFunc;
    hmodule = LoadLibrary("consoleIP.dll" );
    if(hmodule == NULL){
        printf("DLL load Failed\n");
        return 101;
    }

    setValDllFunc = (setValDll)GetProcAddress(hmodule, "setValue");
    setValDllFunc(&firstIp, &secondIp);

}
```

//test.exe code

```
HMODULE dllModule;
typedef float (__cdecl * addVal)(void);
typedef void (__cdecl * setValDll)(float *,float *);

main(){
    addVal addFuncAddr;
    setValDll setValFromDll;
    float test1;
    float test2;

    dllModule = LoadLibrary(calcFunc.dll");

    addFuncAddr = (addVal)GetProcAddress(dllModule, "Add");
    returnVal = addFuncAddr(); // Works fine

    setValFromDll = (setValDll)GetProcAddress(dllModule,"setValue");
    setValFromDll(&test1, &test2); // Access Violation exception

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to directly call `setValue` from test.exe?

As per the use case I need to have the scenarios for my project.

Any help up will be great.

Comment: setValue is to be loaded from `consoleIP.dll` not from `calcFunc.dll`. Is the given code really the one you use?

Comment: @Mathieu, Yes, this is the code i am working. If i load both the dlls from test.exe then calling to func setValFromDll works as expected. But i want call the func like the above mentioned way.

Comment: Modified the design to remove nested dependency with consoleIP.dll and calcFunc.dll. Problem solved by calling both the dlls sequentially.